# Adding a rollover state to a Spark Button when state is disabled

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flex-spark

I need to add a rollover effect to the disabled state of a Spark button.  This way, users can rollover the button and know why the button is disabled.

I think I would have to override ButtonBase's getCurrentSkinState.  Is there anyway to test if a mouse cursor is over a disabled button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following:

```
package
{
import spark.components.Button;

[SkinState("overDisabled")]
public class ButtonWithOverInDisabled extends Button
{
    private var _enabledInvalidaationPhase:Boolean = false;

    private var _explicitMouseChildren:Boolean = true;

    private var _explicitMouseEnabled:Boolean = true;

    override public function get enabled():Boolean
    {
        if (_enabledInvalidaationPhase)
            return true;
        return super.enabled;
    }

    override public function set enabled(value:Boolean):void
    {
        _enabledInvalidaationPhase = true;
        super.enabled = value;
        super.mouseChildren = _explicitMouseChildren;
        super.mouseEnabled = _explicitMouseEnabled;
        _enabledInvalidaationPhase = false;
    }

    override public function set mouseChildren(value:Boolean):void
    {
        super.mouseChildren = value;
        _explicitMouseChildren = value;
    }

    override public function set mouseEnabled(value:Boolean):void
    {
        super.mouseEnabled = value;
        _explicitMouseEnabled = value;
    }

    override protected function getCurrentSkinState():String
    {
        if ((hovered || mouseCaptured) && !enabled)
            return "overDisabled";
        return super.getCurrentSkinState();
    }
}
}
```

Spark skin may looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" minWidth="21" minHeight="21" alpha.disabledState="0.5">
    <fx:Metadata>[HostComponent("ButtonWithOverInDisabled")]</fx:Metadata>
    <fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
        <![CDATA[         
            /* Define the skin elements that should not be colorized. 
            For button, the graphics are colorized but the label is not. */
            static private const exclusions:Array = ["labelDisplay"];

            /** 
             * @private
             */     
            override public function get colorizeExclusions():Array {return exclusions;}

            /**
             * @private
             */
            override protected function initializationComplete():void
            {
                useChromeColor = true;
                super.initializationComplete();
            }  

            /**
             *  @private
             */
            override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number) : void
            {
                var cr:Number = getStyle("cornerRadius");

                if (cornerRadius != cr)
                {
                    cornerRadius = cr;
                    shadow.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                    fill.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                    lowlight.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                    highlight.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                    border.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                }

                if (highlightStroke) highlightStroke.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                if (hldownstroke1) hldownstroke1.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                if (hldownstroke2) hldownstroke2.radiusX = cornerRadius;

                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
            }

            private var cornerRadius:Number = 2;
        ]]>        
    </fx:Script>

    <!-- states -->
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="up" />
        <s:State name="over" stateGroups="overState" />
        <s:State name="down" />
        <s:State name="disabled" stateGroups="disabledState" />
        <s:State name="overDisabled" stateGroups="overState,disabledState" />
    </s:states>

    <!-- layer 1: shadow -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="shadow" left="-1" right="-1" top="-1" bottom="-1" radiusX="2">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" 
                                 color.down="0xFFFFFF"
                                 alpha="0.01"
                                 alpha.down="0" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" 
                                 color.down="0xFFFFFF" 
                                 alpha="0.07"
                                 alpha.down="0.5" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 2: fill -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="fill" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" radiusX="2">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" 
                                 color.overState="0xBBBDBD" 
                                 color.down="0xAAAAAA" 
                                 alpha="0.85" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xD8D8D8" 
                                 color.overState="0x9FA0A1" 
                                 color.down="0x929496" 
                                 alpha="0.85" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 3: fill lowlight -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="lowlight" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" radiusX="2">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="270">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" ratio="0.0" alpha="0.0627" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" ratio="0.48" alpha="0.0099" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" ratio="0.48001" alpha="0" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 4: fill highlight -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="highlight" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" radiusX="2">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF"
                                 ratio="0.0"
                                 alpha="0.33" 
                                 alpha.overState="0.22" 
                                 alpha.down="0.12"/>
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF"
                                 ratio="0.48"
                                 alpha="0.33"
                                 alpha.overState="0.22"
                                 alpha.down="0.12" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF"
                                 ratio="0.48001"
                                 alpha="0" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 5: highlight stroke (all states except down) -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="highlightStroke" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" radiusX="2" excludeFrom="down">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" alpha.overState="0.22" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xD8D8D8" alpha.overState="0.22" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 6: highlight stroke (down state only) -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="hldownstroke1" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" radiusX="2" includeIn="down">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.25" ratio="0.0" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.25" ratio="0.001" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.07" ratio="0.0011" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.07" ratio="0.965" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.00" ratio="0.9651" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="hldownstroke2" left="2" right="2" top="2" bottom="2" radiusX="2" includeIn="down">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.09" ratio="0.0" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.00" ratio="0.0001" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 7: border - put on top of the fill so it doesn't disappear when scale is less than 1 -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" width="69" height="20" radiusX="2">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" 
                                 alpha="0.5625"
                                 alpha.down="0.6375" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" 
                                 alpha="0.75" 
                                 alpha.down="0.85" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 8: text -->
    <!--- @copy spark.components.supportClasses.ButtonBase#labelDisplay -->
    <s:Label id="labelDisplay"
             textAlign="center"
             verticalAlign="middle"
             maxDisplayedLines="1"
             horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="1"
             left="10" right="10" top="2" bottom="2">
    </s:Label>

</s:SparkSkin>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I tried it, it does not work.  getCurrentSkinState is not called when 
the button is disabled.

Comment: Ok, you're right. Now I've tested code with the real button and modified it. So now desired button works properly :) Please test it in your environment and leave your feedback :)